# generate a image from scratch?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

how would I go about creating a pixel image from scratch? I am using web technologies (html/css/javascript/react) how would I take some information (such as pixel 1 is  #ff5733 color, pixel 2 is #ff3829 color) and generate the corresponding pixel image for that? If anyone could point me in the right direction in generating images at least, that would be awesome.

I can only find information on how to pixelate existing images online. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Edit: The two answers below are really good! Thank you all for your fantastic help!

Comment: There are a vast amount of image processing and creation tools available. Are you asking to create bitmap images on the fly using html/css/js ? Why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that you have a two-dimensional array of color values, -- represented below by the variable: **mypixels**, -- you could use a set of for loops to draw each pixel on a canvas, then convert it to an image:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

 var mypixels = [
  ['#FFF', '#FFF', '#FFF', '#FFF', '#FFF', '#FFF', '#FFF'],
  ['#FFF', '#FFF', '#F00', '#FFF', '#F70', '#FFF', '#FFF'],
  ['#FFF', '#FFF', '#F70', '#FFF', '#FF0', '#FFF', '#FFF'],
  ['#FFF', '#FFF', '#FF0', '#FFF', '#0F0', '#FFF', '#FFF'],
  ['#FFF', '#FFF', '#FFF', '#FFF', '#FFF', '#FFF', '#FFF'],
  ['#FFF', '#FF0', '#FFF', '#FFF', '#FFF', '#F0F', '#FFF'],
  ['#FFF', '#FFF', '#0F0', '#0FF', '#00F', '#FFF', '#FFF'],
  ['#FFF', '#FFF', '#FFF', '#FFF', '#FFF', '#FFF', '#FFF']
 ];

 function createImage(pixels) {
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.width = pixels[0].length;
  canvas.height = pixels.length;
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  for(var r = 0; r < canvas.height; r++) {
   for(var c = 0; c < canvas.width; c++) {
    context.fillStyle = pixels[r][c];
    context.fillRect(c, r, 1, 1);
   }
  }
  return canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
 }

 document.querySelector('img').src = createImage(mypixels);

});
```

```css
img {
 width: 200px;
 height: 100px;
 border: 1px dashed black;
 background-color: lightgray;
 image-rendering: pixelated;
 object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <img/>
 </body>
</html>
```

For more information on the Javascript Canvas API, [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API) has a nice reference, and [W3Schools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API) has a nice beginner friendly walkthrough. Hopefully this is useful to you!

Comment: Thank you so much for the clear and concise example! I wish I could set multiple responses as accepted answers. anyway thank you so much! This is very helpful! Thank you!

Comment: So the canvas.toDataURL('image/png'); line converts the pixels to the actual image? Sorry I am a real web noob

Comment: Ok, I didn't see the links at the bottom. This all really helps alot. Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm glad I could be of assistance!

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE**

SVG solution with downloadable image.

**Overview**

There are various ways to dynamically create a simulation of a bitmap image in the context of html/css/js. None of them is efficient nor do they seem to be particularly useful -  - though there is a precedent of a website selling individual pixels for charity purposes ...

The following alternatives are demonstrated:

1. A grid of divs representing pixels
2. A linear gradient representing a row of pixels
3. An embedded svg with rect elements representing pixels
   (UPDATE: with download link)

**1. A grid of divs representing pixels**

***Idea***

Dynamically create 1x1 divs organized in a tabular grid to represent the pixels of the image and set their background color according to the value for the respective pixel.

***Code***

The image data are the html color codes for the pixels organized as an array of arrays in row-major fashion. For demo purposes the rendered 'pixels' are set to the size of 16x16.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"   content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="expires"        content="0">
        <meta http-equiv="cache-control"  content="private">
        <meta http-equiv="pragma"         content="no-cache">
        <title>SO - Bitmap divs</title>
        <!--
        -->
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                background-color:   #eee;
            }
            .bitmap {
                display:    table;
            }
            .bitmap > div {
                display:    table-row;
            }
            .pixel {
                width:              16px;
                height:             16px;
                display:            table-cell;
            }
        </style>
        <script type=text/javascript>
            document.addEventListener ( 'DOMContentLoaded', () => {
                // Image definition as pixel bitmap
                let aas_smiley = [
                    [ ['#aaaaaa'], ['#aaaaaa'], ['#000000'], ['#000000'], ['#000000'], ['#aaaaaa'], ['#aaaaaa'], ['#aaaaaa'] ]
                  , [ ['#aaaaaa'], ['#000000'], ['#cccc00'], ['#cccc00'], ['#cccc00'], ['#000000'], ['#aaaaaa'], ['#aaaaaa'] ]
                  , [ ['#000000'], ['#cccc00'], ['#000000'], ['#cccc00'], ['#000000'], ['#cccc00'], ['#000000'], ['#aaaaaa'] ]
                  , [ ['#000000'], ['#cccc00'], ['#cccc00'], ['#cccc00'], ['#cccc00'], ['#cccc00'], ['#000000'], ['#aaaaaa'] ]
                  , [ ['#000000'], ['#cccc00'], ['#cccc00'], ['#000000'], ['#cccc00'], ['#cccc00'], ['#000000'], ['#aaaaaa'] ]
                  , [ ['#aaaaaa'], ['#000000'], ['#cccc00'], ['#cccc00'], ['#cccc00'], ['#000000'], ['#aaaaaa'], ['#aaaaaa'] ]
                  , [ ['#aaaaaa'], ['#aaaaaa'], ['#000000'], ['#000000'], ['#000000'], ['#aaaaaa'], ['#aaaaaa'], ['#aaaaaa'] ]
                  , [ ['#aaaaaa'], ['#aaaaaa'], ['#aaaaaa'], ['#aaaaaa'], ['#aaaaaa'], ['#aaaaaa'], ['#aaaaaa'], ['#aaaaaa'] ]
                ];
                
                let e_table = document.querySelector('.bitmap')
                  ;
                  
                aas_smiley.forEach ( pa_line => { 
                    let e_row = document.createElement('div')
                      ;
                    
                    pa_line.forEach ( (pa_pixel, pn_idx) => {
                        let e_d = document.createElement('div')
                          ;
                          
                        e_d.classList.add('pixel');
                        e_d.setAttribute('style', `background-color: ${pa_pixel[0]};`);
                        e_row.append(e_d);
                    });
                    e_table.append(e_row);  
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="bitmap"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**2. A linear gradient representing a row of pixels**

***Idea***

A similar effect can be achieved by creating a somewhat degenerate linear gradient of pixel-wide sub-gradients that interpolate between identical color-value.

A minor technical difference here is that the divs carrying the gradient data cover a whole table row, thus the table layout is nx1.

***Code***

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"   content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="expires"        content="0">
        <meta http-equiv="cache-control"  content="private">
        <meta http-equiv="pragma"         content="no-cache">
        <title>SO - Bitmap divs</title>
        <!--
        -->
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                background-color:   #eee;
            }
            .bitmap {
                display:    table;
            }
            .bitmap > div {
                display:            table-row;
                width:              128px;
                height:             16px;
            }
            .bitmap > div > div {
                width:              128px;
                height:             16px;
                display:            table-cell;
            }
        </style>
        <script type=text/javascript>
            document.addEventListener ( 'DOMContentLoaded', () => {
                // Image definition as pixel bitmap
                let aas_smiley = [
                    [ ['#aaaaaa'], ['#aaaaaa'], ['#000000'], ['#000000'], ['#000000'], ['#aaaaaa'], ['#aaaaaa'], ['#aaaaaa'] ]
                  , [ ['#aaaaaa'], ['#000000'], ['#cccc00'], ['#cccc00'], ['#cccc00'], ['#000000'], ['#aaaaaa'], ['#aaaaaa'] ]
                  , [ ['#000000'], ['#cccc00'], ['#000000'], ['#cccc00'], ['#000000'], ['#cccc00'], ['#000000'], ['#aaaaaa'] ]
                  , [ ['#000000'], ['#cccc00'], ['#cccc00'], ['#cccc00'], ['#cccc00'], ['#cccc00'], ['#000000'], ['#aaaaaa'] ]
                  , [ ['#000000'], ['#cccc00'], ['#cccc00'], ['#000000'], ['#cccc00'], ['#cccc00'], ['#000000'], ['#aaaaaa'] ]
                  , [ ['#aaaaaa'], ['#000000'], ['#cccc00'], ['#cccc00'], ['#cccc00'], ['#000000'], ['#aaaaaa'], ['#aaaaaa'] ]
                  , [ ['#aaaaaa'], ['#aaaaaa'], ['#000000'], ['#000000'], ['#000000'], ['#aaaaaa'], ['#aaaaaa'], ['#aaaaaa'] ]
                  , [ ['#aaaaaa'], ['#aaaaaa'], ['#aaaaaa'], ['#aaaaaa'], ['#aaaaaa'], ['#aaaaaa'], ['#aaaaaa'], ['#aaaaaa'] ]
                ];
                
                const n_factor = 16;
                let e_table = document.querySelector('.bitmap')
                  ;
                  
                aas_smiley.forEach ( pa_line => { 
                    let e_row  = document.createElement('div')
                      , e_cell = document.createElement('div')
                      , as_gradient = []
                      , s_gradientStyle
                      , s_lastPixel
                      ;
                    
                    pa_line.forEach ( (pa_pixel, pn_idx) => {
                        if (pn_idx === 0) {
                            as_gradient.push ( `to right` );
                        } else {
                            as_gradient.push ( `${s_lastPixel} ${pn_idx * n_factor}px, ${pa_pixel[0]} ${pn_idx * n_factor}px` );
                        }
                        s_lastPixel = pa_pixel[0];
                    });
                    
                    s_gradientStyle = `background: linear-gradient(${as_gradient.join(', ')});`;
                    e_cell.setAttribute('style', s_gradientStyle);
                    e_row.append(e_cell);
                    e_table.append(e_row);
                });
            });
        </script>
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="bitmap"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**3. An embedded svg with rect elements representing pixels**

***Idea***

Create `rect` elements representing pixels.

Note that elements need to be created in the svg namespace.

****UPDATE**** The code below comes with the generation of an extra download link by means of a [data url](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URLs). In principle this technique can be applied to generate downloadable data in every format that has a MIME type assigned, in particular traditional image formats like gif, jpeg, png, tiff. Of course, you have to obtain the syntactically well-formed octet sequence first ...

Data urls can also be shown inline. To this behest, create an `img` element and set its `src` attribute to the data url string. (see the code section commented out).

***Code***

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"   content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="expires"        content="0">
        <meta http-equiv="cache-control"  content="private">
        <meta http-equiv="pragma"         content="no-cache">
        <title>SO - Bitmap (svg)</title>
        <!--
        -->
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                background-color:   #eee;
            }
        </style>
        <script type=text/javascript>
            document.addEventListener ( 'DOMContentLoaded', () => {
                // Image definition as pixel bitmap
                let aas_smiley = [
                    [ ['#aaaaaa'], ['#aaaaaa'], ['#000000'], ['#000000'], ['#000000'], ['#aaaaaa'], ['#aaaaaa'], ['#aaaaaa'] ]
                  , [ ['#aaaaaa'], ['#000000'], ['#cccc00'], ['#cccc00'], ['#cccc00'], ['#000000'], ['#aaaaaa'], ['#aaaaaa'] ]
                  , [ ['#000000'], ['#cccc00'], ['#000000'], ['#cccc00'], ['#000000'], ['#cccc00'], ['#000000'], ['#aaaaaa'] ]
                  , [ ['#000000'], ['#cccc00'], ['#cccc00'], ['#cccc00'], ['#cccc00'], ['#cccc00'], ['#000000'], ['#aaaaaa'] ]
                  , [ ['#000000'], ['#cccc00'], ['#cccc00'], ['#000000'], ['#cccc00'], ['#cccc00'], ['#000000'], ['#aaaaaa'] ]
                  , [ ['#aaaaaa'], ['#000000'], ['#cccc00'], ['#cccc00'], ['#cccc00'], ['#000000'], ['#aaaaaa'], ['#aaaaaa'] ]
                  , [ ['#aaaaaa'], ['#aaaaaa'], ['#000000'], ['#000000'], ['#000000'], ['#aaaaaa'], ['#aaaaaa'], ['#aaaaaa'] ]
                  , [ ['#aaaaaa'], ['#aaaaaa'], ['#aaaaaa'], ['#aaaaaa'], ['#aaaaaa'], ['#aaaaaa'], ['#aaaaaa'], ['#aaaaaa'] ]
                ];
                
                const n_factor = 16;
                let e_svg = document.querySelector('svg')
                  ;
                  
                aas_smiley.forEach ( (pa_line, pn_row) => { 
                    pa_line.forEach ( (pa_pixel, pn_col) => {
                        let e_rect = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'rect')
                          ;
                          
                        e_rect.setAttribute('x', `${pn_col}`);
                        e_rect.setAttribute('y', `${pn_row}`);
                        e_rect.setAttribute('width' , '1');
                        e_rect.setAttribute('height', '1');
                        e_rect.setAttribute('fill'  , pa_pixel[0]);

                        e_svg.append(e_rect);
                    });
                });

                // Goodie: Downloadable Image
                let s_svg       = e_svg.outerHTML
                  , s_datauri   = `data:image/svg+xml;utf8;base64,${btoa(s_svg)}`
                  , e_a         = document.createElement('a')
                  , e_body      = document.querySelector('body')
                  ;
                  
                e_a.setAttribute('href'     , s_datauri);
                e_a.setAttribute('download' , 'smiley.svg');
                e_a.innerText = 'Download as "smiley.svg"';
                e_body.append(e_a);

                // Optional: Render as inline image with data url
                // let e_img = document.createElement('img')
                //   ;
                // e_img.setAttribute('src'     , s_datauri);
                // e_body.append(e_img);
            });
        </script>
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <svg
            width="128"
            height="128"
            viewBox="0 0 16 16"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        >
        </svg>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: wow, thanks so much! I was actually thinking of doing the same, a grid with divs representing each pixel. Also, thank you for going above and beyond with this whole example, greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sorry for the noob question, but how would I create the image and then make it downloadable? The context is that i will already have the pixel image made on the grid (like a online pixel art maker) but I want to download it. So I would fetch the color of each div in the grid but how to convert that into a image that I can then download?

Comment: That would require to create a octet sequence matching the syntax of some image file format, not so easy. Best bet would probably be to turn the embedded svg into  this kind of sequence.

Comment: I have updated the SVG solution to create an extra download link